# Does use of CSS animation graphics makes your website heavy and slow?

Tags: css, performance, animation, load

So i was trying my hands on some web designing. I added some css animation into my page now i am experiencing problems with the design (the navigation bar is not working properly when scrolled).
Also it runs slower on mobile.
The website is [deepanshubatra.tk](http://deepanshubatra.tk/) .

Comment: The website performance seems to be fine:
http://www.webpagetest.org/result/150907_PB_ZEF/
https://gtmetrix.com/reports/deepanshubatra.tk/R8vdFEpf

Answer (score -1):

http://quirktools.com/screenfly/#u=http%3A//deepanshubatra.tk/&w=1024&h=600&a=1\

It looks ok except header is not scaled to device resolution.

On my mobile site works same speed as on desktop

Comment: Yes i haven't made it responsive yet. Thanks by the way.